# alert Dialog how can I change the font?

Tags: java, android

I need to change the font to my alertDialog (custom font in assets folder is exist), in the Dialog I have buttons,(positive and negative), and items to check, how can I change the font to all elemants in my dialog?
 I'm creating the dialog in code, it's not a custom dialog with xml;

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use dialogfragment to acheive this, create a design you want to display

> ```
> public class ApproveDialog extends DialogFragment {
> @Nullable @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
> {
> View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, container, false);
> TextView styleText=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.styleText);
> Typdface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(),"abc.ttf");
> styleText.setTypeface(tf);
> return v;
> }
> }
> ```

2. To call fragment use

> ```
> FragmentTransaction ft=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
> Fragment prev = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog1");
>                 if (prev != null)
>                     ft.remove(prev);
>                 ft.addToBackStack(null);
>                 // Create and show the dialog.
>                 ApproveDialog newFragment = new ApproveDialog();
>                 newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
> ```

3. custom_dialog.xml

> `<TextView id="@+id/styleText">`

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you add xml code to items of the dialog?

Comment: I didn't understand the step 2, where I need to put it? In fragment activity?

Comment: the line getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() didn't compile to me... where  to create the dialog?

Comment: 1) You should use AppCompatActivity activity instead of Activity or FragmentActivity(getSupportFragmentManager is available to that) 2) Layout is common layout design you used to create in activity

Comment: You can go through this post to more clearification http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Answer (score 0):

To change your Dialog **system** can be used the following code. You use alert builder to build your alert. You then get the TextView and EditView from this alert and then you set the typeface for the alert.

```
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Hello").setTitle("Title Alert").show();
    TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    Typeface face= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "segoe.ttf");
    int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android"); if (titleId > 0) {
        TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(titleId);
        if (dialogTitle != null) {
            dialogTitle.setTypeface(face);
        }
    }
    textView.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: I tried this way, but it's not work, I have dialog with items and buttons and you'r answer is about simple dialog with text only, do you have more ideas?

Comment: Yes Please explain more about your problem.

Comment: I have alertDialog with items that the  user can check one of them, I connect an OnClick function to them, and I need to change the font to my dialog, in assets folder I puted the custom font, now I'm looking for a simple way to  connect the custom font (XXX.ttf) to my dialog, and to change the font to all Views in this dialog, not the title only, thank you!

Comment: You test this code`int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier( "alertTitle", "id", "android" );
if (titleId > 0) {
   TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) dialogObject.findViewById(titleId);
   if (dialogTitle != null) {

   }
}`

Comment: where to put this code? after creating the dialog? like this: builder.show();
           int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier( "alertTitle", "id", "android" ); if (titleId > 0) { TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(titleId); if (dialogTitle != null) { } }

Comment: thank you for your edited, but I want to change the items of dialog, and buttons, where in your code you did it?

Comment: thank you for your edited, but I want to change the items of dialog, and buttons, where in your code you did it? the items are buttons, so I need that when the user will click on them the on click function will call,